# str to float problems; what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, types

I am trying to get a string to a float so I can do math with it.  I have tried many methods including floatval().  The answers always return to a big, fat, 0.  I have also tried casting and get the same result.  I have tried it with single variables and arrays.  Here is the current code I am wrestling with:

```
<?php
$sim = array("$1.99","$0.75","$0.25");

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i+=1)
    $som[$i] = floatval($sim[$i]);

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i+=1)
{
    echo $som[$i];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Remove the leading `$` from the string value before you try to cast it.

Comment: First of all, hard-coding a dollar sign a in string defined with double codes needs to be escaped with `\`. Second of all, type casting strings to int or float in PHP requires the string to start with the float or int directly, with no other preceding characters.

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing the dollar sign first with `str_replace('$', '', $sim[$i])`

Comment: @AlexanderGardner Please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you most as 'accepted' http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

You could also use substr to get rid of the $ in your string.

```
$sim = array("$1.99","$0.75","$0.25");
    
    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i+=1)
        $som[$i] = (float)(substr($sim[$i], 1));
    
    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i+=1)
    {
        echo $som[$i];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

Here are some useful links.

https://www.php.net/language.types.type-juggling

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion